# New dataframe column using existing column names as values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

| ID | Class | LR | XG | SV | BEST_R2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Class1 | .76 | .78 | .99 | .99 |
| 2 | Class2 | .92 | .89 | .91 | .92 |
| 3 | Class3 | .87 | .95 | .87 | .95 |

This is a dataframe with the R2 of each of a series of machine learning models (LR/XG/SV) for each ID. The column "BEST_R2" represents the best R2 score for that ID across models (.max(axis=1)). I need another column with the model name for best score. For example, the dataframe below. Any tips on how to achieve this programmatically?

| ID | Class | LR | XG | SV | BEST_R2 | BEST MODEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Class1 | .76 | .78 | .99 | .99 | SV |
| 2 | Class2 | .92 | .89 | .91 | .92 | LR |
| 3 | Class3 | .87 | .95 | .87 | .95 | XG |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `ID` is the index, you can do

```py
df["Best Model"] = df[["LR", "XG", "SV"]].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Result:

```py
      LR    XG    SV  BEST_R2 Best Model
ID                                      
1   0.76  0.78  0.99     0.99         SV
2   0.92  0.89  0.91     0.92         LR
3   0.87  0.95  0.87     0.95         XG
```

Comment: I included a simplified version of the dataframe I'm working with in the OP. The real DF has a column with non-numeric values, so I need to only select the value of LR, XG, or SV which is the highest and use that values column name as the new columns (Best Model) value. I've updated the DF in the OP to reflect this. Your code works only if I reset the index to the Class column and set that as numeric. It works, though, so thanks!

Comment: @Dr.Data Thanks for the feedback! It's mostly just a matter of selecting the relevant columns, I edited my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

```
best_models = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    tuples = sorted([('LR',row.LR), ('XG',row.XG), ('SV',row.SV)],reverse = True, key = lambda x:x[1])
    best_models.append(tuples[0][0])
df['Best Models'] = best_models
df
```

[image]